# Thread-safe serializable Collection with atomic replace

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization, collections, copyonwritearraylist

I am facing a problem in my program when multiple threads access the same server over RMI. The server contains a list as a cache and performs some expensive computation sometimes changing that list. After the computation finished the list will be serialized and sent to the client.

**First Problem:** if the list is changed while being serialized (e.g. by a different client requesting some data) a `ConcurrentModificationException` is (probably) thrown, resulting in a `EOFException` for the RMI call / the deserialization on the client-side.

Therefore I need a some kind of list-structure which is "stable" for serialization while possibly being changed by a different thread.

**Solutions we tried**:

- regular ArrayList / Set - not working because of concurrency
- deep-copying the entire structure before every serialization - faaar too expensive
- `CopyOnWriteArrayList` - expensive as well since it copies the list **and**

revealing the **Second Problem**: we need to be able to atomically replace any element in the list which is currently not thread-safe (first delete, then add (which is even more expensive)) or only doable by locking the list and therefore only doing the different threads in sequence.

Therefore my **question** is:

> Do you know of a `Collection` implementation which allows us to `serialize` the Collection thread-safe while other Threads modify it `and` which contains some way of `atomically replacing` elements?
>
> A bonus would be if the list would `not` need to be `copied` before serialization! Creating a snapshot for every serialization would be okay, but still meh :/

Illustration of the problem (C=compute, A=add to list, R=remove from list, S=serialize)

```
Thread1 Thread2
      C 
      A
      A C
      C A
      S C
      S R <---- Remove and add have to be performed without Thread1 serializing 
      S A <---- anything in between (atomically) - and it has to be done without 
      S S       blocking other threads computations and serializations for long
        S       and not third thread must be allowed to start serializing in this
        S       in-between state
        S
```

Comment: When you delete, then add, is it essential that the replacement is at the end of the list?

Comment: @PaulBoddington No, the order does not matter, we could use a Set as well.

Comment: What do you mean by removal? Are you removing element with known index (like `remove(index)`) or use search and remove (like `remove(Object)`)?

Comment: @TagirValeev `replaceWithObj(Object, Object)`, not by Index but by checking every object for equality. And currently by calling `remove(Object)` and then `add(slightlyDifferentObj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wrong initial thought was that the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` was a bad idea since it copies everything. But of course it does only perform a shallow copy, copying only the references, not a deep copy copying all Objects as well.

Therefore we clearly went with the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` because it already offered a lot of the needed functionality. The only remaining problem was the `replace` which even got more complex to be a `addIfAbsentOrReplace`.

We tried the `CopyOnWriteArraySet` but that did not fit our need because it only offered `addIfAbsent`. But in our case we had a instance of a class `C` called `c1` which we needed to store and then replace with a updated new instance `c2`. Of course we overwrite `equals` and `hashCode`. Now we had to choose wether or not we wanted the equality to return `true` or `false` for the two only minimally different objects. Both options did not work, because

- `true` would mean that the objects are the same and the set would not even bother adding the new object `c2` because `c1` already is in
- `false` would mean `c2` would be added but `c1` would not be removed

Therefore `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. That list already offers a

```
public void replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> operator) { ... }
```

which somewhat fits our needs. It lets us replace the object we need via custom comparison.

We utilized it in the following way:

```
protected <T extends OurSpecialClass> void addIfAbsentOrReplace(T toAdd, List<T> elementList) {
    OurSpecialClassReplaceOperator<T> op = new OurSpecialClassReplaceOperator<>(toAdd);
    synchronized (elementList) {
        elementList.replaceAll(op);
        if (!op.isReplaced()) {
            elementList.add(toAdd);
        }
    }
}

private class OurSpecialClassReplaceOperator<T extends OurSpecialClass> implements UnaryOperator<T> {

    private boolean replaced = false;

    private T toAdd;

    public OurSpecialClassReplaceOperator(T toAdd) {
        this.toAdd = toAdd;
    }

    @Override
    public T apply(T toAdd) {
        if (this.toAdd.getID().equals(toAdd.getID())) {
            replaced = true;
            return this.toAdd;
        }

        return toAdd;
    }

    public boolean isReplaced() {
        return replaced;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to imply external synchronization to the `ArrayList`, possibly via read-write lock like this:

```
public class SyncList<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6184959782243333803L;

    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private transient Lock readLock, writeLock;

    public SyncList() {
        ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
        writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
    }

    public void add(T element) {
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            list.add(element);
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            return list.get(index);
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public String dump() {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            return list.toString();
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean replace(T old, T newElement) {
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            int pos = list.indexOf(old);
            if (pos < 0)
                return false;
            list.set(pos, newElement);
            return true;
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            out.writeObject(list);
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        list = (List<T>) in.readObject();
        ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
        writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
    }
}
```

Provide any operations you like, just properly use either read-lock or write-lock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will give that a try at work tomorrow. Using two separate locks for reading and writing looks promising. I will have to check if that fulfills all my needs!

Comment: But given the information revealed in the comments (“we could use a Set as well”), replacing `ArrayList` with `HashSet` would be very recommended, as it allows getting rid of the linear search in the `replace` method.